# How to Set TextView Text Inside Thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm trying to update my balance TextView text every time the balance changes. I update the value of the balance within a method that I call within a separate thread, which is started by pressing a button. Once I call `balanceView.setText(balanceString)`, the app crashes. What is the proper way to update a TextView's text value within a separate thread?

```
    private boolean working = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_work);

        CreateWorkButtonListener();
    }

    private void CreateWorkButtonListener() {
        Button workButton = findViewById(R.id.workActivityWorkButton);
        workButton.setOnClickListener(
                v -> StartStopWorking(workButton)
        );
    }


    private void StartStopWorking(Button workButton) {
        if (working) {
            working = false;
            workButton.setText(R.string.start_working);
        }
        else {
            working = true;
            workButton.setText(R.string.stop_working);
            new Thread(this::StartMakingMoney).start();
        }
    }


    private void StartMakingMoney() {
        while(working) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                UserInfo.balance = UserInfo.balance + 1 * UserInfo.workMultiplier;
                UserInfo.totalWorkTime++;
                UserInfo.CalculateWorkMultiplier();
                UserInfo.SaveUserInfoToFile();
                String balanceString = "$" + String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%,.2f", UserInfo.balance);
                TextView balanceView = findViewById(R.id.workActivityBalanceField);
                balanceView.setText(balanceString);   // THIS LINE CRASHES
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println("Error with sleeping for work");
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // NO EXCEPTIONS GET CAUGHT HERE
                System.err.println("Error with setting the balanceView text");
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Here is the stacktrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
Process: com.ggz.cowsino, PID: 20926
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. Expected: main Calling: Thread-2
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:9994)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2082)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:27043)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:27043)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:27043)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:27043)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:27043)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:27043)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.requestLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:3605)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:27043)
at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:11296)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:7179)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6994)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6946)
at com.ggz.cowsino.activities.WorkActivity.StartMakingMoney(WorkActivity.java:76)
at com.ggz.cowsino.activities.WorkActivity.$r8$lambda$yk-GWYweqGH21rtYG7QGFga2zhA(Unknown Source:0)
at com.ggz.cowsino.activities.WorkActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
```

Comment: Can you expand on "the app crashes?"  What error do you get?  What's the full stack trace?

Comment: On Swing (not Android) the UI thread must be used to update GUI objects.  So `setText()` would not be allowed for that reason.  Try `invokeLater()` to update that value on the UI thread.

Comment: @markspace I've updated the description with the stack trace. I'll try using `invokeLater()`, but `setText()` works on android in every other scenario I've tried other than this multi-threading scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi). It appears you have to use `Activity.runOnUiThread()` in order to update views while multithreading on android. This was my solution:

```
runOnUiThread(() -> {
   String balanceString = "$" + String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%,.2f", UserInfo.balance);
   TextView balanceView = findViewById(R.id.workActivityBalanceField);
   balanceView.setText(balanceString);
});
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution.  I'm glad to know the correct name for Android is `runOnUiThread()`, I looked at it years ago and thought it was the same as Swing.  Watch `UserInfo.balance`, it needs to be unmodified and thread safe.  It might be better to copy that value to a local variable, so that the compiler can just copy the value (safely) into your lambda.

Comment: considering that you found an existing answer to your question, this is just a duplicate then, right ?