# Android: ProgressDialog not showing immediately

Tags: android, multithreading, delay, progressdialog

I have a problem of showing the progressDialog on android. It did shows up to the screen but it took few seconds before it really show the dialog.

This is the code i did to show the dialog

```
Handler saveHandler = new Handler() {

                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    GallerySaveActivity.this.Submit(progress);

                    Button btn_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
                    btn_next.setEnabled(true); 
                }
            };
            progress.showDialog(saveHandler, "", "Accessing Facebook ...");
            Thread progress_thread = new Thread(progress); 
            progress_thread.start();
```

Do I have to do any extra work on the Thread object in order to show the dialog instantly without any delay.

Comment: Why do you need an additional thread? ProgressDialog should run in UI thread... Can you post your progress dialog creation routine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798443/android-progressdialog-doesnt-show I do that if operation is heavy. But it shouldn't delay to show the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html): show your dialog in [`onPreExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29), and do your background tasks in [`doInBackground()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29).